# I need a developer for a custom extension where is the best place to ask?

Tags: extension

All is in the title. We have a client with specific need. We would like to hire a developer to build the extension the right way and share it with the community. Where's the place to do it ? Here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious place to start is the list of experts at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors and select **custom code and extensions**

Answer (score 2):

I am currently talking to a few developers for custom extensions. I suggest checking out CiviCRM extensions authors and contacting them personally (for e.g CiviCOOP, AgiliWay)

Answer (score 1):

You can either find under https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors or post a enquiry on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/extensions